# Issues in initializing Pentaho biserver with postgresql on a Mac

Tags: macos, postgresql, pentaho

I'm trying to get pentaho server BI installed with postgresql on a macos. 
When I launch http://localhost:8080/pentaho/, I get the following error:
[image]
And I'm also getting the following errors on pentaho log file :

```
2017-10-17 16:31:33,237 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR:column am.amcanorder does not exist
Position : 407
2017-10-17 16:31:33,239 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] could    not complete schema update
```

I really don't know from where to start to fix these as I'm new to both pentane and mac. Any hint please?

Answer (score 0):

What type of install did you choose: SourceForge/Pentaho web site, Manual/Standard,... Tell us which file you did download, and what you did to configure it with postgres...

Comment: Thanks AlainD, it's now resolved, I was using an old version of pentaho, now that I opted for version 7.1, it's working properly